# how to pass variables to Orderby Clause using Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am getting an error while trying to achieve dynamic sorting in DQL's `ORDER BY` clause with Doctrine 2 ORM.

Here is my code snippet:

```php
$queryBuilder = $categoryEntity->createQueryBuilder('category');

$queryBuilder->distinct();
$queryBuilder->join('Category\Entity\CategoryName', 'category_name', 'WITH', 'category.id = category_name.category');


if($column == 'status'){
    $queryBuilder->orderBy("category.status $order");
}else{
    $queryBuilder->orderBy("category_name.name $order");
}
```

This produces the following error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 189: Error: Expected end of string, got 'ASC'

Comment: You can always use QueryBuilder's getSQL function to get a clue as to where your query is malformed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct API is `Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder#orderBy($field, $direction)`:

```php
// assuming $order is either 'ASC' or 'DESC'

if($column == 'status'){
      $queryBuilder->orderBy('category.status', $order);
}else{
     $queryBuilder->orderBy('category_name.name', $order);
}
```